# How to select multiple alternate checkboxes in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
driver.get("183.82.103.245/nareshit/login.php"); 
driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName")).sendKeys("nareshit"); 
driver.findElement(By.name("txtPassword")).sendKeys("nareshit");
driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switchTo().frame("rightMenu");
List<WebElement> AllCheckboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));;
int size = AllCheckboxes.size();
System.out.println(size);
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    (AllCheckboxes).get(i).click(); 
}
Thread.sleep(5000); driver.close(); 
} }
```

[image: checkbox]

How to select multiple alternate checkboxes in selenium webdriver?

I have written code for selecting multiple checkboxes at a time. I wanted to try for clicking on multiple alternate checkboxes.

Comment: Please share your code including the url to the page you are working on. Currently this question is missing debugging details, focus etc.

Comment: driver.get("http://183.82.103.245/nareshit/login.php");
  driver.findElement(By.name("txtUserName")).sendKeys("nareshit");
  driver.findElement(By.name("txtPassword")).sendKeys("nareshit");
  driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click();
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  driver.switchTo().frame("rightMenu");
  List<WebElement> AllCheckboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));;
  int size = AllCheckboxes.size();
  System.out.println(size);
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
  {
   (AllCheckboxes).get(i).click();
  }
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  
  driver.close();
 }

}

Comment: not here! in the question itself. Make it readable

Comment: Also when I executed the above code, frst it selected all the checkboxes and then started deselecting them,is this behaviour expected? Please refer to image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve that - clicking alternate checkboxes, just add a simple logic:

```
int counter = 1;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) { 
    counter++;
    if ((counter % 2) == 0) {
        (AllCheckboxes).get(i).click(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before actioning on checkboxes, make sure they enables or not and then try to execute the code.

```
    List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.name(""element));
    
    for(int i=0; i<checkboxes.size(); i+=2) {
        
        if(checkboxes.get(i).isDisplayed() && checkboxes.get(i).isEnabled()) {
            
            checkboxes.get(i).click();
```